# Low accuracy during inference for Sbert Cross Encoder

Tags: encoder

I have an sbert Cross-Encoder model to evaluate sentence pairs. The first sentence is a ticket description and the second is the description of category it falls into. The test accuracy is ~90 p.c on the sentence pairs. But when I run inference on each of my sentence1 's with sentence2 and rank the probabilities the accuracy is only 50p.c on the top 5 i.e to say that the actual sentence pair is still coming out as high probability but not in the top5. I am trying more hard negative sampling, but would like to know if anyone has experiences this